# Is the sentence "Whoever is at door, they can’t come in right now" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

More exactly, is "at door" correct? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Did you try to Google "at the door"' and "at door"? I've just found there is a huge difference in results. Our community doesn't encourage a simple question without any research efforts. Especially, is it coorect? type of question is not welcome. Please visit our [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, you can consider visiting our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The first clause should be "Whoever is at *the* door" (emphasis added).